# How to create an Application specific configuration in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have an application developed in Grails 2.0.4, I am hard coding some of the values in my domain classes, example as follows

```
class Training{
  String startTime ="09:00"
  String endTime  ="17:00"
}
```

But Its not good approach, Making changes is overhead, Like this I have got more than 10 domain classes where the values are hard coded.

So, I am planning to create a separate configuration Domain class, thereby I can input the values through the UI (view) and persist them.

This is my plan, Is there any solution in grails to deal with it.

**UPDATED:**

```
import org.grails.plugins.settings.*

class PublicTraining extends Training{
    Date startDate = Setting.valueFor("startDate")
}
```

I have created a setting 'startDate'.  I am able to access setting using  Setting.valueFor("startDate") method in controllers but not in domain classes

The error I am getting is below

```
*Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectcom.springpeople.tms.PublicTraining
    ... 5 more
*Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 5 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.plugins.settings.Setting.methodMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at org.grails.plugins.settings.Setting.valueFor(Setting.groovy:53)**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Settings](http://grails.org/plugin/settings) plugin.  I use it in almost every project.  Allows you to create any number of these type of config settings and access them in GSP's or Contollers/Services/etc.  It even provides a CRUD gui to manage them.

```
//programatically
import org.grails.plugins.settings.*

def startTime = Setting.valueFor("startTime")
def endTime = Setting.valueFor("endTime")

//gsp
<g:setting valueFor="startTime" default="9:00" encodeAs="HTML" />
```

To use it in domain classes I've always used the `beforeInsert` or `beforeUpdate` events.

Handles settings of types String, Integer, BigDecimal or Date.

If you had multiple values that are similar(like "Training start time" and "Inventory start time") you needed to store you can segment them as `inventory.startTime` and `training.startTime` as well.

Comment: cannot able to access Setting.valueFor("startTime") from domain classes, giving me error

Comment: What is the error?  Did you add the import statement `import org.grails.plugins.settings.*`

Comment: yes, I did, I have got two projects, In one project I can able to read the fields but in the other one, Only in the domain classes I can't.

Comment: No signature of method: org.grails.plugins.settings.Setting.methodMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] at org.grails.plugins.settings.Setting.valueFor(Setting.groovy:53)

Comment: I know people always ask this but did you run a `grails clean` and then try again?  If that does't do it can you update to include the domain class where you are getting the error?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase that very well.  Can you update your  question to show the domain class code that is still giving you the error?

Comment: Vinay, I've updated your code above to show what I have done.  I usually use the `beforeInsert` or `beforeUpdate` events to do things like this.